# iOS 7 Status Bar not over top of views without editing every view

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I've seen the answers on each of these questions:

[Status bar appear over my view's bounds in iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18375898/status-bar-appear-over-my-views-bounds-in-ios-7)

[Status bar and navigation bar appear over my view's bounds in iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17074365/status-bar-and-navigation-bar-appear-over-my-views-bounds-in-ios-7)

[New iOS 7 statusBar leaves a range 20px in apps compiled in Xcode 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17116315/new-ios-7-statusbar-leaves-a-range-20px-in-apps-compiled-in-xcode-5)

[iOS 7 status bar back to iOS 6 default style in iPhone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18294872/ios-7-status-bar-back-to-ios-6-style)

However, none of those answers seem to work for me. I am trying to show the status bar in the "Black Opaque" style, as I have set in the `.plist`.

Is there any way to have the application continue to work as if the status bar wasn't included in the window?

I've tried this:

```
CGFloat statusBarHeight = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame].size.height;
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, statusBarHeight, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height - statusBarHeight)];
```

However, `statusBarHeight` is `0` in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`. And manually setting it to `20.0f` seemed to just screw up the `UIWindow` and the `UIViewController`s would be taller than the screen. (Also, manually setting the value 20.0f feels dirty)

What am I missing?

EDIT

I should also point out that I am using a `UINavigationController` that hides it's `UINaviationBar`.

EDIT 2:

This only seems to be an issue for the application while debugging or in Ad Hoc (Test Flight) release. The exact same application on the App Store shows the status bar as it should. Why is this affecting debug and ad-hoc releases?

Comment: Your "edit 2" is curious - the app behaving differently from appstore vs ad-hoc. My guess would be that as part of the submission, some script on AppStore side overrode some properties inside the package. Download the .ipa with itunes, compare content for differences?

Comment: @NasBanov It was. It was switching SDKs that were used. TestFlight used the iOS 7 SDK, but the App Store used the iOS 6 SDK, as iOS 7 was not out at the time.

Answer (score 1):

Set `UIViewController.edgesForExtendedLayout` to `UIRectEdge.None`

[image: Edges For Extended Layout]

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to affect my content at all. Also, I am setting the `UINavigationBar` to hidden.

Comment: I'm an idiot. I was setting that to the wrong `UIViewController`. I was setting it to the `UINavigationController`'s `rootViewController`. However, will I also have to set something to the frame, as it currently continues to include the `UIStatusBar` as a part of the controller.

Comment: Try additionally setting `UIViewController.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars` to `YES`

Comment: That also doesn't work. I'm not using Interface Builder, either. This is all using code. I am not setting the `UIWindow` size to anything other than the `UIScreen` bounds, as when I try to shrink it, it only pushes the window down and doesn't affect the height of the `UIViewController`s. The navigation bar remains over top of the content.

Comment: This does seem to work while the `UINavigationController`'s `UINavigationBar` isn't set to hidden. When it is hidden, such as when using a custom navigation bar, both of those options seem to not have any effect.